# Increase number of parallel caching tasks for GeoWebCache?

Tags: tiles, geowebcache, limitations

By default GWC has limitation of 16 parallel caching tasks.

Is it possible to increase this limitation?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. By default it supports 16 parallel tasks. You can create cache for smaller zoom levels (it takes less time) then try for larger cache (it takes long time) this way you can optimize your work + its depend on your data (raster/vector). Why you want more caching tasks ?

Comment: @Sunil because i'm trying to cache from 0 to 14 zoom levels. 0-13 zoom levels have cached already in ~20 hours. Now i'm caching 14 zoom level using 16 parallel tasks and it takes 3 days to cache all tiles. 14 level is the last zoom level I need to cache